# why TTN_NEEDTEXTW but not TTN_NEEDTEXTA?

Tags: winapi, mfc, tchar

This is an old problem that I've never figured out - wondered if someone here might happen to know the answer off of the top of your head...

In some parts of our software (MFC/Win32/MBCS) my code will only receive

TTN_NEEDTEXTW

In other parts of our software, I'll receive the MBCS correct message

TTN_NEEDTEXTA

It makes no sense to me.

I understand that our software can be compiled Unicode or not (we are set to use Multibyte character set).  And I have the vague recollection that each window can be constructed Unicode or not, though this is a vague memory, nothing concrete.

Does anyone know why we'd be getting the wide version message some places in our code, despite being compiled as multibyte?

NOTES:

- We're definitely not sending this message - presumably the ToolTip control is.
- We're definitely only receiving the (W) message in some places, and definitely only receiving the (A) message in others.
- I'm certain that all compilation modules use MBCS, not Unicode, and that the build targets all specify MBCS not Unicode.
- This seems to happen only for CMainFrame hosted windows and controls.  i.e. Windows outside of the main frame can use narrow versions (say in a dialog box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common control sends you a `WM_NOTIFYFORMAT` message to ask you "Would you prefer to receive MBCS notifications or Unicode notifications?" The default is to respond based on whether the window was created via `CreateWindowExW` or `CreateWindowExA`.

Comment: Minor nit: the use of RegisterClassExA/RegisterClassExW determines a window's unicode status.

Comment: This makes sense, but so far no luck on seeing why our CFrameWnd derived window and hosted controls would be receiving the W variant for a MBCS build.  Tracing startup shows that RegisterClassA and CreateWindowA are being called during class registration & creation.  Even stranger still, WM_NOTIFYFORMAT is only referred to in our code for tracing purposes, and in the VC++ include paths to define its numeric identity & for the ON_WM_NOTIFYFORMAT() macro.  Maybe when the tooltip control is being initialized there is another way to tell it what message type to send?

Comment: Is it possible that the tooltip is being created by some other code? (For example, the listview control creates its own tooltip.)

Comment: So far no luck figuring this out.  It's an old MFC multi doc app, with both the CMainFrame and the the only view CMyView being entities that seem to get only W variations in the tooltip notifications.  Dialogs, property sheets all get the correct A variations.  The CMyView is a CView derivative, no CListView or other complications there.  Sorry, obviously we're doing something to get the wrong message - and it's a big app, so I'll have to poke at this as/when I have time.  Not a big deal, just one of those "huh?" moments, where I didn't know the rules so hard to interpret the results...

Answer (score 2):

With an MFC ansi app (that handles unicode data), I had this issue with CStatic derived classes and tooltip where I was getting TTN_NEEDTEXTA instead of, in my case, the desired TTN_NEEDTEXTW.

Using the accepted answer, managed to get TTN_NEEDTEXTW.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStaticDerived, CStatic)
ON_WM_NOTIFYFORMAT()
ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXTW, 0, 0xFFFF, OnTTNeedText)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

UINT CStaticDerived::OnNotifyFormat(
    CWnd *pWnd,
    UINT nCommand) {

    if (pWnd->m_hWnd
            == AfxGetModuleThreadState()->m_pToolTip->m_hWnd) {
        // want TTN_NEEDTEXTW for tooltips
        return NFR_UNICODE;
    }

    return __super::OnNotifyFormat(pWnd, nCommand);
}
```